FirebaseAuth error and network error in ios flutter app
When I run my iOS app on a physical device, it gets stuck on the loader page, and I need to kill the app and restart it. I do not get this error on the emulator or Android phones.
When I run the app in Xcode, I see logs like:
[FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] AppCheck failed: 'The operation couldn't be completed. 
The attestation provider DeviceCheckProvider is not supported on current platform and OS version.'
[FirebaseAuth][I-AUT000018] Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead.
nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C68] Connection has no local endpoint

Additionally, I see these logs in Xcode:
nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal_block_invoke [C70] Client called nw_connection_copy_protocol_metadata_internal on unconnected nw_connection
nw_connection_copy_connected_local_endpoint_block_invoke [C68] Connection has no local endpoint
...
[FirebaseAuth][I-AUT000018] Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead.
Error: Error Domain=com.google.app_check_core Code=4 "The attestation provider DeviceCheckProvider is not supported on current platform and OS version."
UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The attestation provider DeviceCheckProvider is not supported on current platform and OS version.

How can I fix this issue and ensure my app runs smoothly on a physical iOS device?
